# Null Space and Range are the same for a Matrix $A$ and its Hermitian $B$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a complex $n \times n$ matrix, and $B$ its hermitian transpose. Suppose that $A$ and $B$ commute. Prove they have the same image and kernel.

I tried something like the below...but it doesn't look right to me.

Let $v \in ker(A)$ so that $Av=0$. Taking the conjugate transpose gives us $Av = 0 \iff v^*A^* = 0 \iff v^*B = 0 \iff ... ?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A matrix $A$ for which $A,A^{*}$ commute (where $A^{*}$ is the Hermitian transpose) is called normal. A basic fact about normal matrices is that for all $v \in \mathbb{C}^n$ we have $\| Av \| = \| A^{*} v \|$. The reason is that

$$ \| Av \|^2 = \left< Av, Av \right> = \left< v, A^{*}Av \right> = \left< v, AA^{*}v \right> = \left< A^{*}v, A^{*}v \right> = \| A^{*}v \|^2. $$

In particular, this implies that $Av = 0$ iff $A^{*}v = 0$ so $A$ and $A^{*}$ has the same kernel. Then

$$ \operatorname{Im}(A) = \operatorname{ker}(A^{*})^{\perp} = \operatorname{ker}(A)^{\perp} = \operatorname{Im}(A^{*}) $$

so $A,A^{*}$ also have the same image.